# The definite article before “English commentary”

Tags: definite-article

Consider these examples:

> 1. I would prefer reading the manual in **the** English language. *(Definite article before ‘English language’)*
> 2. I would prefer watching the match in English commentary. *(No definite article before ‘English commentary’)*

Why is that we are using the definite article in the sentence 1, but not in the sentence 2? Will the sentence still mean the same if we say **the English commentary** here?

Comment: Both of the sentences will be good by themselves without the definite article. However, it would sound weird if you use _the_ in the second sentence, unlike the first one.

Comment: I would say _with an English commentary_, but perhaps I'm just out of touch with the jargon.

Comment: @KateBunting English is so complicated, it’s so hard to figure out when to use an article in such cases. An Australian guy said it’s only “English commentary (no article needed)”; most or some might say it’s “an English commentary”. It’s very ambiguous.